# How to change currency format to Indian Rupee in ms access?

Tags: vb.net, ms-access-2007

I am creating winform application using vb.net and MS ACCESS. I have an Amount field in my table which stores Amount in Rupees(Indian). To do this i set the datatype of that field to currency. But it stores in $ format like $1,780,000.00. This is not rupees format. I need to store like Rs 17,80,000.00 how to do this? I tried this bye editing the format property :
"Rs "#,##0.00 which results with R 1,780,000.00 but i have problem with digit grouping. It should be in the order from right to left 3,2,2,2. So I tried "Rs "##,##,##0.00 . When i do this automatically it set it back to "Rs "#,##0.00 . How can i change it? Please Help me. if this is possible to set manually i also want to do this programmatically. Because this table is done using the code : 
cmd.CommandText = "CREATE TABLE tblventries (amt currency not null)"
Please Help Me......

Comment: I simply changed the settings in Region and Language. But I did it manually ...  !!! It Worked.

Answer (score 1):

```
Dim cost As Double = 2524000
Dim str As String = cost.ToString("C", New System.Globalization.CultureInfo("hi-IN"))
str = str.Remove(0, 3)
Label1.Text = str
```